signature verification issue with crypt32.dll CryptMsgControl api
We have an application which transfer EDI documents using AS2 protocol where When we send data to one of our business partner and try to verify the signature of the MDN that business partner return to us and we can`t verify the signature of the MDN that business partner return to us.
We are reading the certificate from windows certificate store using CertGetSubjectCertificateFromStore api and verifying the signature using the below code. error code return from the below code - CRYPT_E_SIGNER_NOT_FOUND
if (CryptMsgControl(m_hCryptMsg, 0, CMSG_CTRL_VERIFY_SIGNATURE, pRet->pCertInfo))
{
     bSigVerified = true;
     dwError = 0;
}
else
{
     dwError = GetLastError();
}

Same solution is working every other partners that we are transferring the files.
we have check with partner but so far did not find any solution, I really appreciate if someone help here, let me know if need more information.

Is the certificate trusted by Windows ? Is the message formatted correctly as PKCS#7?

Yes we have install certificate which provided by partner and install under Windows Personal and Trust Root Certificate and yes message is formatted correctly as PKCS#7

we have verified signature using the .pem file and we are getting
CryptMsgControl (CMSG_CTRL_VERIFY_SIGNATURE) failed with error -2146889714: Cannot find the original signer.

I suggest you could try to check the entire certificate chain is available and trusted. And you could check whether the signer information provided to the CryptMsgControl function is correct and matches the signer of the message.
